# htaccess need help rewriting url and improving code

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a local site on localhost and i want to clean up the URL.
I have already written some code but I need help perfecting it.

My URL: `localhost/root/pages/videos/videos.php`
URL that i want: `localhost/root/videos/`

1. I want to remove .php and instead add a slash
2. If a user doesn't put a slash at the end then add a slash
3. If the user puts .php in the URL then redirect to a 404 page
4. I want to remove the sub directory pages and videos
5. If the user is in a directory (not a file) then redirect to a 404 page

This is the code I already have:

```
# Adds a 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /root/pages/errors/404.php

# Turn on RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

Options All -Indexes

# Redirect .php to 404 page
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [L,R=404]

# Redirect non slash to slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /root/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Rewrite .php to slash
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/$ /root/pages/videos/$1.php [L]
```

Issues: 
1. If I'm in the directory localhost/root/ and when I add for example the text something behind that I get redirected to localhost/root/pages/videos/something.php/

Comment: Hi Milan, please can you change the title of your post. Make sure that the title is a clear question, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post I uploaded

Comment: Why would you want to respond with a 404 on a request to a php file? Redirect it instead. You want to answer to requests, not grumble to clients.